# Does anyone have problems with the gzip compression provided by RIM?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, compression, gzip

I am new to Java ME and to BlackBerry development. I'm trying to compress a byte array using `GZIPOutputStream` class from the package `net.rim.device.api.compress`.

If I compress a byte array, it works, but if I try to decompress the result using `GZIPInputStream`, it does not work.

I  wrote also a simple Java app to compress and decompress byte arrays by using the objects provided by the Java JDK and it works fine.

If I compress a Byte Array using the app I wrote in Java, I can decompress it with the decompress method I wrote for BlackBerry. The problem is that what I compress with the method provided by BlackBerry cannot be decompressed.

Did anyone encounter a similar problem? I'm using the compresion method from their official documentation http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/6.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/compress/GZIPInputStream.html and SDK 7.1 .

Comment: Perhaps something to do with char encoding? BB uses ISO-8859-1 by default.